# DataGrid column selection events

Tags: flash, apache-flex, datagrid, adobe, edit

What event is called when you click on an editable field to edit it, and then click off of the field? in a datagrid using Flex 4? If I'm not making much sense I'm trying to make a datagrid where you can edit the fields and once you're done editing those fields the application calls an event listener which triggers a save method.

Comment: Found it, how can I close this?

Comment: Instead of closing it, you could answer your own question and click the green checkmark to mark it as the answer. That way anyone else who comes along with the same question can use what you found as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for future reference:

DataGridEvent.itemEditBegin and DataGridEvent.itemEditEnd.

From the [flex docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#event%3aitemEditBegin).